# Aligning buttons on different views

Tags: zurb-foundation

I have a button which I want to align to the right on a desktop, which is easy with the `right` utility class:

```
<div class="small-12 columns">
  <a href="#" class="button right">bla</a>
</div>
```

But on a smartphone I want the button NOT float to the right, so how can I achieve this?
Basically it is just not using the `right` class, but I need that for the desktop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom class to you button use media queries to style on smartphone/

HTML :

```
<div class="small-12 columns">
  <a href="#" class="button right mybutton">bla</a>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
  .mybutton{
    float:none !important;
  }
}
```